# Google maps api, several moving markers using a csv file containing the coordinates

Tags: data, database, google-maps-api, markers

I collected 5 sets of coordinates of moving vehicles and I want to play the scene using googlemaps API showing those 5 vehicles moving. 
The sets are saved in a postgresql table.

is it possible ? if yes how ?

what I found for the moment is only one vehicle.

Comment: Are these 'moving vehicles' live? Google Maps API terms 10.2 c You must not use the Service or Content"(iii) enterprise dispatch, fleet management, business asset tracking or similar applications" https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.  One way would be to make a php webservice that sends either part or all of the vehicle traces as a json output to a website.  On your website you could have javascript that handles the displaying of a Google Map and also creates markers representing your vehicles.  Then you could set a javascript timer that updates the map by requesting the gps location of the vehicles from the server at a specific time (or it could just go through a large json object returned from the server when the page loads).